# How to find the list with the the first value is the largest in python

Tags: python

Here i have a list of lists:

```
m = [[[0.5898237279659958, 620, 200]],[[0.58557319664958118, 720, 200]],[[0.5959494936867108, 820, 200]], [[0.59444930616327041, 920, 200]]]
```

I would like to find out the list which first value is the largest, for example, in m, i need to find out this [[0.5959494936867108, 820, 200]]

Comment: this task/question was answered many-many times on SO ... it remains to only find already working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
m = [[[0.5898237279659958, 620, 200]],[[0.58557319664958118, 720, 200]],[[0.5959494936867108, 820, 200]], [[0.59444930616327041, 920, 200]]]
final_m = max(m, key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Output:

```
[[0.5959494936867108, 820, 200]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Lists are sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), so your answer is simply:

```
>>> max(m)
[[0.5959494936867108, 820, 200]]
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you don't need the double square brackets; this should work:

```
 m = [[0.5898237279659958, 620, 200],[0.58557319664958118, 720, 200], [0.5959494936867108, 820, 200], [0.59444930616327041, 920, 200]]
        nums = []
        for l in m:
            nums.append(l[0]) #Puts the first value of each list into a list, 
                              #0 can be changed to position in the list you want
        nums.sort() #Puts the largest value last
        cornum = nums[-1] #Gets the last number
        for l in m:
            if cornum in l: #checks if the number is in each of the lists in m
                print(l)
```

Comment: It is a bit longer than the others, but it allows you to get the list with the highest `list[x]` value, where `x` can be anything